# hash md5 password in jQuery security

Tags: jquery, md5

I have an Admin panel where You can make CRUD Ops on User,

I'm Using C# asp.net MVC,

I want to know,Is it safe to hash password in jQuery and send the encrypted password to server?

Because my application implementation it is easier for me to do that.

many thanks in advance

Comment: See [How to securely hash passwords, The Theory](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846) on Security Stackexchange.

See OWASP (Open Web Application Security Project) [Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Leverage_an_adaptive_one-way_function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. First rule of client/server application architecture is that you can't trust the client. It resides completely on its own, outside of your control, and can be manipulated by anyone (with or without skill). In your case, someone could easily send a password to your server without hashing, among any number of other possibilities.

Use encryption via HTTPS to send the raw password, and then hash and store it on your server. I would also **strongly advise against using MD5**. Passwords hashed with it are exceedingly easy to crack either through a [rainbow table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) or simple brute force. MD5 also has [known collisions](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1436) which is very very bad.

Comment: Simply using any hash is insecure. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.